# Resonance structures of benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

Does benzene have more than two resonance structures? I draw a third resonance structure keeping 1 bond fixed and rotating other two bonds I get opposite charges on two para position. Is this structure wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are many resonance structures which contribute to the overall reality of benzene.

Some of these contain charges, the higher the energy of a resonance form the less it contributes to the overall reality. Consider the "normal" resonance forms of benzene which most people think of.

[image]

Next we have some with two charges in them, I have not drawn all the possible resonance forms with two charges. Sadly if I draw all of the resonance forms possible I have to stay up very late and I will miss out on my beauty sleep (maybe at midnight I will turn into a pumpkin).

[image]

Here are the two highest energy resonance forms which I can think of, these will make a minimal contribution to the overall reality. But it is good to be aware that they exist.

[image]